# Calling WCF Service from Power builder-11.5

Tags: wcf, powerbuilder

Please help me. I have a power builder - 11.5 version installed and i can/t upgrade to 12.0.
Now the problem is i have to call the WCF Service from power builder.

Please let me know if this is possible. If Yes, then please provide me some examples/code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this: [Real's how to - Get data from the Internet](http://www.rgagnon.com/pbdetails/pb-0128.html)?
I use a slight variation of the same concept:

```
internetresult uo_result  
inet iinet_base  
long ll_ret  
string ls_url  

ll_ret = GetContextService("Internet", iinet_base)  
IF ll_ret < 0 then  
    MessageBox("Error", "Error...", StopSign!)  
    Return  
End IF  

uo_result = CREATE uo_internetresult  
ll_ret = iinet_base.geturl(ls_url, uo_result)
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to consume **WCF** web services using PB11.5.

If you can add new code to the project then I think you could create a workaround.  I don't have sample code but you can create a .NET assembly using Visual Studio and .NET 3.5 (PB11.5 doesn't support .NET 4) that acts as a proxy to your WCF web service, then you can use the new assembly in your PB11.5 program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wizard in power builder for proxy creation.

1. In that wizard you just need to input url of wcf service
2. Select .net then create a proxy
3. use that proxy in code